# Gradient Notation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation, vector-analysis

I'm studying physics and, doing basic algebra and simple differential equations, I came across an expression which I'm not sure how to correctly interpret.

The expression is:

$$\frac{d f}{d \vec{x}}$$

where $f$ is a scalar function.

Can I simplify that as the gradient?

Comment: Definitely missing context.

Comment: I would interpret it as 'differentiating $f$ along the direction given by the vector $\vec{x}$'.

Comment: This might either be the gradient or possibly the directional derivative depending on the author so you'll need additional context to decide which it is.